# Bloody Nose/Sore Throat from Heavy Breathing During Endurance Sports

Tags: running, long-distance-running, bicycling, marathon

I've recently started cycling and running. I've been getting a dry throat and sometimes a bloody nose from the heavy breathing while doing these activities. I live in Arizona, and it's really hot and dry, so I think it might be the cause. The only thing I've found to help so far has been chewing gum while cycling, and sometimes that doesn't even help. Also, that's not really an option for me while I run, since the breathing is more labored and I don't wanna choke. Does anyone have any tips on how to avoid this?

Comment: You can get hyaluronic acid nose sprays, try one of those to moisturize your mucus membranes?

Comment: This may be unrelated but: Sometime when I get dry nose I eat CHOCOLATE since it produces more mucus; Another strange tip is do not pick your nose clean and keep your finger nails short. (I think sometimes I pick my nose while sleeping and wake up with a bloody pillow); Do not rub you nose, this causes tears that lead to bleeding and irritation later; On a plane or under aircon I wear a mask because the dryness is just annoying. My experience is solely weather driven, not sports related. I hope you find something that helps and I don't sound like a crazy person. :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes, I will try some of that hyaluronic acid spray. And yeah, Clintus, the aircon could definitely be a contributing factor, I've gotten a couple purifiers and swapped out my filter on my A/C unit, so hopefully that helps!